# Periodicity with irrational numbers

Tags: calculus, number-theory, irrational-numbers

Recently, I composed the following math problem and found a solution,
it seems strange since it is very counter-intuitive to me.
Is there a place or a branch of math where I can read about it? Or at least a key word?
Any explanation is definitely welcome!
Sorry for my terminology - I am not a mathematician.

Suppose we are given a set $S = \{i\} \cup \{j \cdot x\},$ where $i, j \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ and $x$ is a positive irrational number. Prove that there exist two real numbers $\alpha$ and positive $T$ such that, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$, the interval $(\alpha + k \cdot T, \alpha + k \cdot T + T),$ contains exactly one number from $S$.

Comment: Perhaps the [equidistribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) is involved somehow

Comment: It's more than that (and I would say claims something opposite), that's why I am puzzled. I claim that multiplies of an irrational number (or an integer) can be bound by some periodic pattern which seems counter-intuitive to me exactly because of the equidistribution theorem.

Comment: A question about the set $S$. Does it consist of the union of the positive integers with the positive integer multiples of the fixed irrational number $x$? [The notation you used seemed unusual, at least to me.]

Comment: Since this is a problem which "you composed", and it does seem so unlikely to be true, I would appreciate it if you'd include in your question an outline of the proof you came up with.

Comment: Yes, the set S is exactly as you defined it. The proof is non-conceptual and long.

Comment: You might look here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence

Comment: Sounds interesting and similar! I will look into it and see if this statement is related to one of the theorems in the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The result is closely related to [Beatty sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence). For more details see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180724/periodicity-with-irrational-numbers/).

P.S. I just noticed Joseph Malkevitch made a similar comment an hour ago.